# WCF throws socket exceptions

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, .net-4.0, socketexception

I am using WCF with NetTcp binding and castle windsor as dependency injection at client side.

I am recieving Socket exceptions at client side sometimes, not always. Tried with different config setting but no luck. exceptions occruence are completely random.

few error messages:

1. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2. System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1+ClientSecurityDuplexSessionChannel[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IDuplexSessionChannel], cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
3. Error loading CubeDrillThroughAttributeSets cache: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: This channel can no longer be used to send messages as the output session was auto-closed due to a server-initiated shutdown. Either disable auto-close by setting the DispatchRuntime.AutomaticInputSessionShutdown to false, or consider modifying the shutdown protocol with the remote server.
4. Error loading Locations cache: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1+ClientSecurityDuplexSessionChannel[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IDuplexSessionChannel], cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.

WCF service is configured with PerCall instance mode.

At the client side, I am using dependency injection to inject WCF service proxy (proxy is created using channel factory).

I am not explicitly opening/closing connection with WCF service and leaving this to DI.

already tried using google. my questions are...

1. using DI for proxy management is good?
2. How the life time of proxy will be managed.
3. These proxies are injected in construtor when user select to load some screens in UI app. Can these proxy be timedout as per defined in client app.config file if user just open some screen and not doing anything. if yes, then what is the good way for not to timedout.
4. are these proxy using WCF connection pooling feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the WCF configured on `PerCall`, it will dispose any clients after your request. But DI, probably, trying to be lazy, and stores one reference to the proxy. Try to change the DI behavior in this specific case for the one class.